# Mysql substring

Tags: mysql, csv, substring

Hi all i'm trying to migrate to  a new mail server so i want to wrote Mysql script to return a table as the following
then  export the result as  CSV file 
sql statement as the following

```
`select email,clear,email AS domain from postfix_users `
```

i want to substring any characters preceding the @ and the @ symbol iteself before the domain name any ideas would be great assist

```
mysql> select email,clear,email AS domain from postfix_users ;

+---------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| email                     | clear  | domain                    |
+---------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| user@domain.tld           | passw  | user@domain.tld           |
+---------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use LOCATE to find the position of the @:

```
 LOCATE('@',email)
```

So to find the domain:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE('@',email) = 0 THEN ''
    ELSE SUBSTRING(email,LOCATE('@',email)+1)
    END as Domain
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: what about selecting email and  clear fields in same statement

Comment: Add "email, clear, " right after SELECT.  Or ", email, clear" right after Domain.

Comment: i tried this it worked
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1)AS email , clear , SUBSTRING(email,LOCATE('@',email)+1) as domain from postfix_users ;